# In graph theory, Is there a term that describes the number of edges associated with a node in a directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I am looking for a term that describes the number of edges associated with a given node in a directed graph. This term should include all edges (inbound and outbound). Does such a word exist in graph theory?

Comment: Degree of the node

Answer (score 3):

For a directed graph, the *degree* of a vertex is sum of the inbound and outbound edges connected to that vertex.

Comment: Another word for the same thing is _valence_.